# SQL Server: How to get total number of backups done in a month?

Tags: sql-server, backup, statistics

I need to gather monthly statistics for my boss, on how many FULL backups were done in a month and which number Succeeded and which failed if any.

Is there a simple query that could give me this, based on SQL Server logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use below script to get history of backups in last 1 month:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
CASE msdb..backupset.type 
WHEN 'D' THEN 'Database' 
WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log' 
END AS backup_type, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size, 
msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.description 
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
WHERE (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102) >= GETDATE() - 30) 
ORDER BY 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date
```

Here `30` is a variable, which can be changed with any number up to which you want backup details however this would work only if you are not archiving backupset table in msdb database.

Please refer below links for detailed info on these backup sets and what is backup fails:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/

[Query that displays backup information (successful and failed) SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57720/query-that-displays-backup-information-successful-and-failed-sql-server)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sort of. I don't get all the backup logs from before Apr 2020, yet when I look at the Error Logs, and filter by BACKUP type, I see everything as far back as Jan 2020. Why?

Comment: Edited my answer, Your question was to get backup in a month and hence above query will give your all backups done in last one month. You can change the value of 30(WHERE (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102) >= GETDATE() - 30)) with your desired number and you should get the result. Also note that, in order to this work, backup set shouldn't be archived in your environment.

Comment: Sorry my response above was based on curiosity (I removed the WHERE line). And that's when I noticed the variance. The original OP stands, and your script does answer it. Thanks